# Issue with fetching data from a web api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, same-origin-policy

So I started watching a tutorial on how to fetch data from a web api, and the first line of code that the instructor writes is this.

```
fetch('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/')
```

He then explains that you can't fetch data from a website that isn't yours because of the same origin policy and uses a workaround which is using the crossorigin.me site. It works for him in the video, but doesn't work for me and it always gives me this error:

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)*

I've been looking for over an hour and I couldn't find a single solution. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: You can not access it if they do not set the CORs headers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: The only way to access it is serverside. If they've not cors-headers you cannot access the data of another website from yours directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or u can use a cors plugin for chrome and use it

Answer (score 0):

From your question, using fetch() means that you are using either javascript or one of it's frameworks, if I may ask, which method are you using as your request method: POST or GET?

Comment: i'm sorry,but i think i'm not that deep in the current lecture i'm watching,so the only line of code that is written is the fetch function,and yes i'm using javascript.

Comment: thanks for checking my questions i used an extension and it worked!